# Python Interpreter Not Found VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, interpreter

So I am having an issue ever since I accidentally deleted python, when I reinstalled it VSCode kept giving me an issue saying "You need to select a Python Interpreter before you start debugging. Tip: click on "Select Python Interpreter" in the status bar." When I go to the bar there are no interpreters available. When I try on my brothers laptop it shows the interpreters. Python is already in the Path.

Comment: you have to install Python first. And in `Select Python Interpreter` should be some icon to search manually Python on disk.

Comment: I've already installed Python, I have IDLE and PyCharm is working fine. It's just VSCode. And when I manually put the python file into the icon nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling VSCode and re-enabling your python extension (e.g. `ms-python.python`) inside VSCode?

Comment: I just had the same issue. I just installed VS Code on my Mac and it could not find the command to select the interpreter. Turns out that I was running in restricted mode! I had to "trust" to enable running program, sorry I did nt take a screenshot at the time!

Answer (score 8):

You should find and choose python interpreter manually:

1. Ctrl+Shift+P, Python: Select Interpreter
2. Enter interpreter path – Find (or enter the path manually)
   [image]
3. Find your python.exe in your python installation path, the default path is like:

   ```
   C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
   ```
4. Check if the problem is solved

OR you can take the following steps to override settings for interpreter

1. Ctrl+Shift+P, Preferences: Open Settings(JSON)
2. Copy your python path
3. Add line like this, paste and replace the path:

   ```
   "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\***\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python.exe"
   ```
4. Ctrl+S to save the changes.

See more for macOS/Linux:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter

Comment: On macOS, make sure to enter the filepath manually instead of using Finder to select the Python interpreter: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22755

Answer (score 4):

Check whether you have the Python extension installed in your Visual Studio Code. If it is already installed, then try to disable/enable it.

Comment: +1 for those who can't even find "Python: Select Interpreter" in VSCode's settings, do as Dharmin said, uninstall python extension and then reinstall it

Comment: how do I check if I have the Python extension installed?

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue with python interpreter but when I completely uninstalled my python package and reinstalled the latest version which currently is 3.9.6  , and it perfectly worked.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled python latest version v3.10.2 and reinstalled v3.9.7 and its working perfectly without no issue.