# Cannot find python kernels corresponding to Virtual environment on remote

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I am visual studio code Version: 1.63.2 (Universal).
I am connected to a linux server where my code is located (jupyter notebook). When i open the notebook and select the python kernel, i can only find the default python kernels (from the server). I cannot find the kernels that i created which is necessary to run the notebooks.

Note: The required kernel is linked to a virtual environment on the kernel.

Please help me in linking the remote kernel to my notebook on vscode so that i can work locally on the notebooks located in remote server.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to install the python extension on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the second method here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62871909

I did a little differently:

1. Ctrl+Shift+P, Preferences: Open Remote Setting (SSH:your_address)
2. Set Python: Default Interpreter Path to your virtual environment Python path
3. Done

Answer (score 0):

i've stumbled upon this post, since i had a similar issue.
*working remotely on a linux server*, even if i selected the right interpreter (via `shift+ctrl+P` "Select Interpreter to start Jupyter server") the kernel remained unactive.
i've checked the installed dependencies inside the venv and tried to switch virtual environment to make it work.. kept on reloading the server, reloading the window.. no way.

eventually, a tiny fancy detail arouse my attention: the "Jupyter server : remote" label in the bottom right.
and tadaa : that was my issue. I've selected "default", letting VSCode starting  a server on the local (remote) host, and then the interpeter / kernel was enabled.

hope it can help anyone stuck on the same issue. [jupyter server location detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czXE8.png)