# How to start kernel on vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've Win11 PC.There is a vscode in it,and,I use Jupyter notebook on vscode.
When I connect the Python kernel, It raise an Error(always that, my python3.10 or anconda all will raise that Error.And It's the same things in Jupyter lab.):

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
d:\python3.10\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2392: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' if you require traitlets >=5.
  warn(
d:\python3.10\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2346: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use 'ecf4c84b-3c42-491a-8c1a-a92fb5e8d52c' instead of 'b"ecf4c84b-3c42-491a-8c1a-a92fb5e8d52c"'.
  warn(
Bad file descriptor (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100).
```

I installed the Jupyter packages,and this is my Jupyter core packages version:

```
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.4.0
ipykernel        : 6.13.0
ipywidgets       : 7.7.0
jupyter_client   : 7.3.4
jupyter_core     : 4.11.1
jupyter_server   : 1.6.4
jupyterlab       : 3.3.4
nbclient         : 0.6.2
nbconvert        : 6.5.0
nbformat         : 5.4.0
notebook         : 6.4.11
qtconsole        : 5.3.0
traitlets        : 5.3.0
```

I searched in Bing,a passages told me the problem is at pyzmq23,I should install pyzmq19.0.2,but it's **fail**(in my WSL:Ubuntu22.04,pyzmq version is 23,but in WSL Python kernel can run).

Why is this?
If you can finish my problem,I would be very grateful.
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62293947/python-interpreter-not-found-vscode) can help you?

Comment: sorry,It can't.Are there any other ways to finish this questions?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by changing the paths of TEMP and TMP from the C drive to the D drive in the environment variables, because TEMP and TMP are in the C drive by default and are accessed when using Jupyter, however, my username is in Chinese and I don't know why it can't seem to resolve the paths of Chinese usernames and I can't seem to change my username, so I changed their path to the D drive. After that it worked fine.