# Unable to run Python is Visual Studio Code - select Python Interpreter Issue

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When attempting to run any kind of python code in Visual Studio Code, i am getting a message that i need to select a python interpreter in the status bar. [image: request message] here is what the status bar looks like: [image].

Issue is i have already installed python multiple times and deleted and installed it too. I have also selected a path a few times but that did not work for some reason. maybe i am not doing the correct path, if so then can someone do a complete instruction on how to get the correct installation and a path.

```
import pickle
import base64
import subprocess


class RCE:
    def __reduce__(self):
        cmd = ('ls')
        return subprocess.check_output, (cmd,)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pickled = pickle.dumps(RCE())
    print(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(pickled))
```

Tried installing and python. also uninstalled brew with python a few times and redid but did not work. tried doing path as well but that failed too.

Comment: did you restart VS Code after installing Python? Where did you install Python from, and how did you install it from there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Interpreter Not Found VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62293947/python-interpreter-not-found-vscode)

Comment: After you installed Python, does `which python` or `which python3` yield a result?

Comment: Have you tried click **Enter Interpreter Path**?

Answer (score 0):

you have copy of path where you installed python on your Computer and past to the field **Select interpreter : python** in status bar as you mentioned
the path of install in my case is
**C:\Users\yourUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe**

to find correct path in your computer do the flowing steps
1- click on windows and type python
2- right click on python and chose the **open file location**
3- right click on python again and chose the **open file location**
4- click on address bar and add **\python.exe** then copy fully path in address bar

Comment: The OP indicated brew which suggests Mac OS X, not Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe check if you installed the right version of Python. You could also try to make a new path that you can have with only the main file and python. This answer might help: [Python Interpreter Not Found VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62293947/python-interpreter-not-found-vscode)

Comment: It does not depend which version of Python if VSCode can't locate it.